# Removed failed disk from

Tags: raid, software-raid, mdadm

I have a problem with a software raid running mirror. One disk is dead and the server cannot find it. Normally I would have removed it as well.

`mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --remove /dev/sda1`

But after it can't see the bad disk I got an error saying it couldn't see /dev/sda1

I then chose to have the disk changed and run the raid again. But if I now do a cat /proc/mdstat it comes up with the following

`md3 : active raid1 sda4[2] sdb4[1]`

Why is there now a [2] and [1] is it because it still sees the old disk as part of the raid?

If it still sees them as part of the raid, how do I remove the partitions when I can't access them because the disk is dead?

Answer (score 0):

Your `md3` array includes `sda4`, not `sda1`.

If `sda` is gone, you can try to remove it from the array via

```
mdadm -r /dev/md3 failed
mdadm -r /dev/md3 detached
```

but be **sure** it is the correct array (`md3`).

If in doubt, *stop now* and post the full output of `cat /proc/mdstat` and `mdadm --detail /dev/md3`